# Top status bar is not showing when expo run:android is run

Tags: android, react-native, expo, build.gradle

**Running an ideal react native app on an emulator**

The below image comes soon after the building process finishes and the app runs smoothly without any problem. This is another project btw.

[image: 1]

**Running expo run:android**

But when I run an expo project using the expo run:android command, the build finishes successfully but after the metro bundler starts, the app shows a white blank screen. And there is no status bar on the top indicating either Downloading bundle or Loading etc. And also when I try to refresh by pressing **R** on the command line, it says ***WARN: No Apps are connected*** really looking forward to an answer. Any help would be a great help. Thanks

[image: 2]